# Combining Worksheet_Change events

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to combine this code with another one that does the same thing but instead of "Closed" it would be for "Waiting RA" and to sheet3.

```vb
Sub closed(Worksheet_Change)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, Columns("E:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Value = "Closed" Then
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A:A").End(3)(2)
    Target.EntireRow.Delete
End If
  
Sheet2.Columns.AutoFit

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: So change `Closed` to Waiting RA and `Sheet2` to `Sheet3`?

Comment: Yeah what are you asking for? Your own question provides the answer so what do you need help with **exactly**?

Comment: I need to combine them

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("E:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Select Case Target.Value             'check value and assign sheet if matched
        Case "Closed": Set ws = Sheet2
        Case "Waiting RA": Set ws = Sheet3
    End Select
    
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then            'any match?
        With Target.EntireRow
            'Not disabling events since this will not result in a loop
            '  (will be filtered out by the `Target.Count > 1` condition)
            .Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Delete
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```